# How can I get the machine IP address only for several PCs using ForEach-Object in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, foreach, ip-address

I am working on a script to get the IP address information from several computers using the `ForEach` statement. Problem is that the IP address string returns extra info, so in order to get rid of that info, I run this...

```
Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration | 
    where { $_.ipaddress -like "1*" } | 
    select -ExpandProperty ipaddress | 
    select -First 1}
```

Which is fine for one computer but when I add it to the whole `ForEach` part of my script below, it returns the IP Address for my machine attached to all machine queried in the script.

```
Get-Content $MultiActivePing | foreach {
    Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -ComputerName $_ |
    where { $_.ipaddress -ne $null} | 
    select @{Expression={$_.__SErver};Label="Computer"}
      ,@{Expression={Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration | where { $_.ipaddress -like "1*" } | select -ExpandProperty ipaddress | select -First 1};Label="IPAddress"} `
      ,@{Expression={$_.DefaultIPGateway};Label="Gateway"} 
                                        }
```

So I was wondering if there was a way to expand the property of the IP address without having to run another `GWMI` inside the `SELECT IP` address portion.

Comment: Could you please cleanup your code a bit?  In this current iteration it's a bit wonky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Admitting I am a little confused since I don't know what you are expecting exactly however I can venture a guess. Mostly I'm not sure what you want the IP Address output to look like.

```
Get-Content $MultiActivePing | ForEach-Object {
    # Save the current computer name so we can use down the line. 
    $computer = $_
    Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -ComputerName $_ |
    where { $_.ipaddress -ne $null} |
    Select @{l="IPAddress";e={$_.ipaddress | Select -First 1}},@{l="Computer";e={$computer}},DHcpenabled,macaddress
}
```

The part about this that will vary depending on what you are trying to accomplish:

```
Select @{l="IPAddress";e={$_.ipaddress | Select -First 1}}
```

You already know the IP so there is no need to acquire it again. This takes the first IP in the array and outputs it alone. This is the part I think you are having issues with but I don't know how you choose what information to drop. The caveat obviously is that you could lose IP information that you actually want depending on the order it appears. I would suggest this then as well so nothing is lost:

Change the calculated property for IPAddress highlighted above to this:

```
@{l="IPAddresses";e={$_.ipaddress -Join ";"}}
```

That would take all IP's and convert them into a semicolon delimited string

Comment: Matt, One thing that I forgot to mention was that my computer was one of the machines on the `$MultiPingActive` text file so when I'd run the the script, it would attach the IP address of my computer to all machines queried in the text file. I am relatively new to Powershell and still trying to figure out how to word my requests. Your script worked perfectly by the way, thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to Matt's logic, I just added this to the script...

```
,@{E={$_.ipaddress | Select -First 1};L="IPAddress"}
```

Here's what it looks like now, something so simple. Took care of my issue...

```
ForEach {
Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -ComputerName $_ |
where { $_.ipaddress -ne $null} |
Select @{E={$_.__SErver};L="Computer"}
      ,@{E={$_.ipaddress | Select -First 1};L="IPAddress"}
      ,@{E={$_.DefaultIPGateway | Select -First 1};L="Gateway"}
```